# Ruby regex that will find a JSON object in the middle of a string

Tags: ruby, regex, json, parsing

I have this regex:

```
 /(
     # define subtypes and build up the json syntax, BNF-grammar-style
     # The {0} is a hack to simply define them as named groups here but not match on them yet
     # I added some atomic grouping to prevent catastrophic backtracking on invalid inputs
     (?<number>  -?(?=[1-9]|0(?!\d))\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?){0}
     (?<boolean> true | false | null ){0}
     (?<string>  " (?>[^"\\\\]* | \\\\ ["\\\\bfnrt\/] | \\\\ u [0-9a-f]{4} )* " ){0}
     (?<array>   \[ (?> \g<json> (?: , \g<json> )* )? \s* \] ){0}
     (?<pair>    \s* \g<string> \s* : \g<json> ){0}
     (?<object>  \{ (?> \g<pair> (?: , \g<pair> )* )? \s* \} ){0}
     (?<json>    \s* (?> \g<number> | \g<boolean> | \g<string> | \g<array> | \g<object> ) \s* ){0}
   )
\A \g<json> \Z
/uix
```

I have an API which is supposed to return JSON, but some of my clients have installed other plugins in their APIs and now my response includes other characters that are not JSON, but the JSON is within the response string.

I believe this regex isn't working because the escape characters are not being recognized by the `<string>` pattern. If I have quotes within a pattern that has been recognized as a `<string>` it doesn't match the pattern. This happens if I have a value that's an HTML string and one of the elements has an attribute, like so:

```
<div itemscope itemtype=\\\"http:\\/\\/schema.org\\/Recipe\\\" id=\\\"zlrecipe-container\\\" class=\\\"serif zlrecipe\\\"></div>
```

Here is [an example](https://gist.github.com/jojo89/c72d9876d8044c47985b) of the response I'm receiving. I want to extract my JSON block and disregard the rest.

Comment: Are you trying to parse HTML? JSON? JSON with HTML in it?

Comment: I'm using open uri and calling open(the_url).read and receiving this string as the response. I am trying to call JSON.parse on the response string, but it will through an "unparsable error" until I have removed the the other characters in the string that are not apart of the block.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example of your response, instead of pointing us to a link. If/when that link breaks, your question will make no sense. Besides, you're asking potential answerers to use extra time to chase down the needed extra information. Don't do that.

Comment: Why don't you tell your clients to NOT do that because they broke their systems. Or, better yet, tell them they broke their system and you now need to charge them a huge amount of money to modify the system to allow them to use other plugins.

Comment: Here is an approximate regexp, which matches on `{\"` and `}}}`: `/(\{\\\".*\}\}\})/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you forgot a `"` in your test JSON string, right after `<\/a><\/div>`, so it was not valid JSON.

I did the test with the following string, which is your corrected and unescaped example:

```
b<---------------->{"status":"ok","plugin_version":"1.2.6","post":{"id":7598,"type":"post","slug":"honeycrisp-apple-sangria-recipe","url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria-recipe\/","status":"publish","title":"Honeycrisp Apple Sangria Recipe","title_plain":"Honeycrisp Apple Sangria Recipe","content":"<div class=\"pin-it-btn-wrapper\"><a href=\"\/\/www.pinterest.com\/pin\/create\/button\/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bigbigbutts.c…crisp-apple-sangria.jpg&description=Honeycrisp%20Apple%20Sangria%20Recipe\" data-pin-do=\"buttonBookmark\" data-pin-config=\"none\"     rel=\"nobox\"><\/a><\/div>","raw_content":"","excerpt":"","date":"2013-08-24T11:18:07+00:00","modified":"2014-04-24T09:45:00+00:00","author":{"id":2,"slug":"gia","name":"gia","first_name":"gia","last_name":"Wenner chia","nickname":"gia","url":"http:\/\/giawennerchia.com","description":"gia Wenner chia is a writer and mom who gets paid to obsess over Pinterest and blogs for Ahalogy, a Cincinnati-based startup. She lives in her hometown of West Chester, Ohio, with her husband, two young children, and their dog."},"attachments":[{"id":7599,"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria.jpg","slug":"honeycrisp-apple-sangria","title":"honeycrisp-apple-sangria","description":"","caption":"","parent":7598,"mime_type":"image\/jpeg","images":{"full":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria.jpg","width":580,"height":406},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria-150x150.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"medium":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria-300x210.jpg","width":300,"height":210},"large":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria.jpg","width":580,"height":406},"Mini Square":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria-70x70.jpg","width":70,"height":70},"Square":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria-115x115.jpg","width":115,"height":115},"Featured Tabs":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria-150x225.jpg","width":150,"height":225}}}],"featured_image":{"id":7599,"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria.jpg","slug":"honeycrisp-apple-sangria","title":"honeycrisp-apple-sangria","description":"","caption":"","parent":7598,"mime_type":"image\/jpeg","images":{"full":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria.jpg","width":580,"height":406},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria-150x150.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"medium":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria-300x210.jpg","width":300,"height":210},"large":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria.jpg","width":580,"height":406},"Mini Square":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria-70x70.jpg","width":70,"height":70},"Square":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria-115x115.jpg","width":115,"height":115},"Featured Tabs":{"url":"http:\/\/www.bigbigbutts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/08\/honeycrisp-apple-sangria-150x225.jpg","width":150,"height":225}}}}}<random shit><dafkdjkfjdak
```

Next, the regex. Those `\A` and `\Z` are wrong, because they make the pattern match only if the JSON is the only string content.

Then, you put too much backslashes in your `string` subpattern. Replace `\\\\` with `\\`.

Another problem is the `[^"\\]*` part in the `string` subpattern. Replace `*` with `+` or `++`, as the whole atomic group has already a `*` quantifier on it.

Here's the working regex, PCRE style:

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<number>  -?(?=[1-9]|0(?!\d))\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)
  (?<boolean> true | false | null )
  (?<string>  " (?:[^"\\]++ | \\ ["\\bfnrt\/] | \\ u [0-9a-f]{4} )* " )
  (?<array>   \[ (?> \g<json> (?: , \g<json> )* )? \s* \] )
  (?<pair>    \s* \g<string> \s* : \g<json> )
  (?<object>  \{ (?> \g<pair> (?: , \g<pair> )* )? \s* \} )
  (?<json>    \s* (?> \g<number> | \g<boolean> | \g<string> | \g<array> | \g<object> ) \s*)
)
\g<json>
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/tS8cW7/1

I still think some atomic groups aren't needed, but they don't hurt after all.

Now, since you're using ruby (Oniguruma), you can't use the `(?(DEFINE)...)` syntax. Your `{0}` trick is good, but using it in one place is enough:

```
(?:
  (?<number>  -?(?=[1-9]|0(?!\d))\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)
  (?<boolean> true | false | null )
  (?<string>  " (?:[^"\\]++ | \\ ["\\bfnrt\/] | \\ u [0-9a-f]{4} )* " )
  (?<array>   \[ (?> \g<json> (?: , \g<json> )* )? \s* \] )
  (?<pair>    \s* \g<string> \s* : \g<json> )
  (?<object>  \{ (?> \g<pair> (?: , \g<pair> )* )? \s* \} )
  (?<json>    \s* (?> \g<number> | \g<boolean> | \g<string> | \g<array> | \g<object> ) \s*)
){0}
\g<json>
```

Comment: +1 Good job. same conclusions for me: http://regex101.com/r/vM3vQ8/1 I have only changed two or three groups and added a kind of anchor at the begining.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks. Your anchor is a good idea. If the JSON is expected to always contain an object, the last line in the regex should be `\g<object>` instead of `\g<json>`. Otherwise, if the prefix string contains numbers for instance, it will match the first number instead of the JSON object.